# angularjs:- $route direct to Url

Tags: angularjs, routes

$route service provides $route.reload().

I am trying to redirect to `someUrl`.

Something like `$route.load('url')` or `$route.redirect('url');`

Can't understand [documentation.](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute.%24route)

Comment: depends where you are trying to do redirect from...can use `$location.path()` as setter or getter  http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$location. More details would help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$location.path( "/toUrl" );  [documentation](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24location) performs thre redirect.